# Jquery UI autocomplete demo - categories, How to get a border directly above the category name?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm struggling getting a border directly **above** the category name in this example (Note: in the example the border is directly **below** the category name.)

http://jsfiddle.net/ectD3/1/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories

How do I get a border directly above the category name?

Also, how would I get a strikethrough-border (without a strikethrough the category name), the way pandora's autocomplete does it for categories like *Top Hits, Artist, Song*(http://www.pandora.com/)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to set some CSS to change the way the categories are displayed in the dropdown:

```
.ui-autocomplete-category {
    color: gray;
    border-bottom: none;
    clear: both;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/N6mmg/